# Cell"s are not showing properly when scrolled

Tags: ios

I have images within a collection view that I can select. When I select an image(s) the wrong image cells is selected. Once I scroll down out of view of the cell then back up the cell is no longer selected. How can I fix this issue?

The imageView is defined in the storyboard.
The assets are in the photo library.

This is the PhotoCell.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface PhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property(nonatomic,strong) ALAsset * asset;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView * PhotoImageView;
```

This is my PhotoCell.m file.

```
#import "PhotoCell.h"
@interface PhotoCell ()

@end

@implementation PhotoCell

#pragma mark - User Made Method 
- (void) setAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
{
    // 2
    _asset = asset;
    self.PhotoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
}

#pragma mark - CollectionView Cell Method
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

PhotoCell *cell =(PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
ALAsset * asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
cell.asset = asset;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

#pragma mark - Collection View Delegate

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //NSLog(@"%@ - %d", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), indexPath.item);       
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    chkboxBtn  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [chkboxBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 30, 30)];
    [chkboxBtn setTag:100];
    [chkboxBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"success.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:chkboxBtn ];
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // This removes the Check Box Button From the Cell After click it again
    PhotoCell *cell =(PhotoCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: Could you spend some more time on your question and try to explain the problem better? Otherwise you won't get any anwers...

Comment: It might possible that i need to spend some time on my question but plz try to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the checkbox in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and remove it in `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`, because all cells will be reused while scrolling.

Add checkbox in your `PhotoCell`, and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function, do this:

```
if cell.selected {
    checkbox.hidden = false
}
else {
    checkbox.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Jacky I didn't know what to do. Could you explain in detail

Comment: i am a new in iPhone sorry to ask you but plz -Jacky, I have cell created in storyboard so where do i need to add chekbox in storyboard or cellforItemAtIndexPath -

Comment: I added my Custom Cell code Jacky . If You could Find out something

Comment: @vikramsingh add checkbox in your storyboard, and set hidden in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. It's a simple question.. you can reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665181/uicollectionview-cell-selection-and-cell-reuse

Comment: My question is i select some images and when i am scrolling the collection view at that point of time my check box is showing on another cell and when  i scroll back selected sell is removed

Answer (score 0):

You should know about how `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` works with tableview cell. When you call `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]`, it will get a cell that has previously been created and isn't currently being used. That means same UITableCell objects reuse when need.

So when you are adding checkbox button at `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` delegate and scrolling to bottom/up, this cell is reusing for another cell index and as a result cell is showing selected.

To solve this problem you need to store selected index path at `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and remove at `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` method.

Finally, reset [remove checkbox & thumb] cell at `cellForItemAtIndexPath` datasource and then mark cell as selected if index path contains in the  selected index path array.

See these below code as example which has not been tested yet.

Add a button from storyboard and make outlet as below:

```
@interface PhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property(nonatomic,strong) ALAsset * asset;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView * PhotoImageView;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton * chkboxBtn;

@end
```

Update PhotoCell as below:

```
#import "PhotoCell.h"

@interface PhotoCell ()

- (void)setCheckBoxSelected:(BOOL)selected

@end

@implementation PhotoCell

#pragma mark - User Made Method
- (void) setAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
{
    // 2
    _asset = asset;
    self.PhotoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
}
- (void)setCheckBoxSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    if (selected) {
        [self.chkboxBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"success.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.chkboxBtn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
@end
```

And finally modify your controller as below
Add a NSMutableArray property in your controller class

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPaths;
```

Initialise array at `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```

And then..

```
#pragma mark - CollectionView Cell Method
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    PhotoCell *cell =(PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ALAsset * asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
    cell.asset = asset;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [cell setCheckBoxSelected:NO];
    } else {
        [cell setCheckBoxSelected:YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Collection View Delegate

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];

    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setCheckBoxSelected:YES];
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // This removes the Check Box Button From the Cell After click it again
    PhotoCell *cell =(PhotoCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setCheckBoxSelected:NO];
    [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
}

@end
```

Hope it will work.

Thanks.