# iOS 10 UICollectionView Cell selection and deselection

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios10

I want to modify my `UICollectionView` Cells on selection and deselection. While `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` work automatically, this doesn't cover more complex cases of wanting to change text colour for example.

Prior to iOS 10 I could simply:

1. configure cell depending on isSelected in `cellForItemAt`
2. modify it to the selected state in `didSelectItemAt`
3. modify it to the de-selected state in `didDeselectItemAt`

However, since iOS 10 changes to UICollectionView, there is a corner case where the cell can go off-screen, I can select an on-screen cell, then roll the previously-selected cell and see it in the selected configuration. I now have two selected cells visually, even though there is only one actually selected cell.

This is because while the cell was off-screen, I couldn't get hold of it in `didDeselectItemAt` to configure it. It remains un-updated until it is recycled.

I think I have found an answer and since I haven't seen it elsewhere, posting it below so it might be helpful. Would appreciate any other ideas to make sure I'm thinking the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a re-phrased duplicate of [UICollectionView cell selection and cell reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665181/uicollectionview-cell-selection-and-cell-reuse/40749073#40749073)

Check out my answer regarding iOS10 in particular below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40749073/2039497